How to deal with large numbers in Zig?
Seems Zig natively supports up to u128. For larger numbers, what's the recommended way of dealing with them?

I haven't used zig that much yet, but I would say you are looking for std.math.big (int_test.zig)

Might also be rrelevant for you Correct BigInt Fibonacci Implementation in Zig Lang

I am curious about practical use case for such large numbers.

Zig supports arbitrarily sized ints from u1 all the way to u65535.
Docs.

I landed here after finding out that zig has BigInts in its standard library and googling "Why does zig have a bigint library" (since it natively supports huge ints already)
